# Splunk query do not return value for both columns together

Tags: splunk-query

The Splunk query below returns only the calc_string column and returns blank for the index column, if I remove the ln4 and ln5 it returns index. How can I make this query to return both columns Please advise??

> index=vehicle*
> sourcetype=info_ssl
> splunk_server_group=ALL
> | stats values(xx) as XX values(yy) as YY
> | eval calc_string=if(isnull(XX), YY, XX)
> | table index calc_string
> | sort index

Answer (score 1):

With the stats command you'll want to use the BY clause to return one row for each distinct value in the BY clause fields.

In your example when using `| stats values(xx)` the result set only consists of the values of field `yy` without the index

So to include the index we'll use the by clause with the stats aggregation (line 2 at the very end)

```
index=vehicle* sourcetype=info_ssl splunk_server_group=ALL 
| stats values(xx) as XX values(yy) as YY BY index
| eval calc_string=if(isnull(XX), YY, XX) 
| table index calc_string
| sort index
```

*If this fixes your problem, take a moment to accept the answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in!*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helps. Though the result is not the same as before.